# vb6 error "Too few parameters, Expected 1."

Tags: sql, vb6, runtime-error

Its obviously an error in an sql statement, I just don't know why. I have used this statement on other parts of the same module however when I run it in this instance it comes up with this error.

The code is this:

```
strQuery = "SELECT [Tablename] FROM Licence_Product WHERE [Product_Code] = '" & rsOrder.Fields(2) & "'"
Set rsProduct = dbLicence.CreateDynaset(strQuery)
```

I'm not sure how much of the code to include so any additional code can be provided. Like I said I have used this exact line elsewhere and it works fine.

Comment: Is `Product_Code` numeric or a string?

Comment: its a string, it has both letters and numbers however.

Comment: `[Tablename]`, `Licence_Product` and `[Product_Code]` are written correctly? The table and the fields exist? `On error resume next` somewhere that hides some other error? `rsOrder.Fields(2)` "exists"?

Comment: Does  Rs.order.fields(2) contain a non-null value at run time? if it's null is it blanking otu the entire query so the strquery is null which is why it's not finding the value for createdynaset?

Comment: can you output the strQuery before it gets the rsProduct.  Is it possible the rsOrder.Fields(2) contains a character which would cause the SQL to fail (perhaps &, ' or some other unhandled specialized character? (depending on RDBMS))  [in oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `Product_Code` is not a string.  Try the following:

```
strQuery = "SELECT [Tablename] FROM Licence_Product WHERE [Product_Code] = " & rsOrder.Fields(2)
```

Comment: so i switched out the code and its giving me the same error but its expecting two parameters now. :(

Comment: So, `Tablename` is an actual field in your `Licence_Product` table?  Try using `SELECT * FROM Licence_Product....` and see what you get.

Comment: thats the one! `SELECT *` did the trick for some reason. i had to change the line back to `'" rsorder.fields(2) "'"` though.

Comment: That would means that `Tablename` is not a valid field of `Licence_Product`.

Comment: you are right, i took a second look trough the DB and someone renamed it Table_Name...